# Can't find DAX function to correctly calculate Sum

Tags: powerbi, dax

I run a simple query in SQL:

```
select count(*) FROM Abattoir.RecordScan_BloodPit
JOIN Abattoir.RecordScan RS ON RS.ScanId = RecordScan_BloodPit.ScanId
WHERE rs.HarvestDate = '07/16/2018'
```

which gives me a correct number of rows (say 2000)

I then go to my measure editor in Power BI, and enter:

```
CALCULATE(COUNT(BloodPit[ScanId]))
```

and get an insane number of around 254000000.

I don't understand why counting on a field so simply would give me a *completely* Different number.

New to DAX so my Google strings might not be the best when conducting searches.

[image: The 2 tables I'm Using]

Here is what the report looks like. Please note the nubers inside the rectangle are what I'm trying to calculate. The numbers vary from day to day...
[image: Report]

Comment: can you post your Power BI data model diagram?

Comment: Is that what you're getting for that particular date or do you not have any date filtering on your measure?

Comment: I am using a splitter to sort the dates. I really don't know how to insert "Date A" into the query. I am editing the post to show what I am trying to achieve

Comment: In your Data view, upon selecting the BloodPit table what is the row count in the bottom left?

Comment: 302271 is the row count for the BloodPit Table and 486,048 for the condemns

Comment: In the Data view, on either of the tables, can you click on the arrow to the right of your date column, and do a date filter to just 7/16/2018? Then look at the count in the bottom. (You can then remove the filter by clicking "Clear filter") If the new count is around expected (from your SQL query of 7/16/2018), the problem is likely with your chart. If not, it may be a problem with the data import.

Comment: It is spot on with the filter. What is wrong with the chart formula?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the formula. Most likely, the problem is with the data model. In your matrix, where does "Date" come from? From which table/field? The same question for your date slicer - what table/field did you use?

Comment: I wound up creating a bridge table of dates and that seemed to bring me in range. Thanks for all of your help